# Reference for Finite groups of Lie type

Tags: finite-groups, groups-of-lie-type

I want to learn about finite groups of Lie type, but I have no experience in Lie groups. What could be a good reference-book/notes for this?

Comment: See [here](http://mathoverflow.net/questions/136880/definition-of-finite-group-of-lie-type), what you need. A good book is the one of [Digne and Michel](http://catdir.loc.gov/catdir/samples/cam034/91210586.pdf).